# Panel data mediation analysis

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, mediation

For my research I need to conduct a mediation analysis on panel data, my data setup is as follows: It is an (unbalanced) panel dataset including about 50 countries and 14 years. I have one dv, one iv and am interested in the mediation effect of this iv by estimating mediation effects of two different mediator variables. In addition, I include 5 control variables.

I have seen loads of similar questions like this on both stackexchange and statalist (I use stata). Unfortunately, the majority remains unanswered and the others do not arrive at a clear solution. So I am starting to doubt whether this is possible at all (atleast in stata).

So my question in short: Is anyone aware of a stata program or command that is capable of (multiple) mediation analysis suitable for panel data? Additionally, I want to add both country and year fixed effects to this model.

I also asked this question and received an answer in:

https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1659266-mediation-analysis-panel-data

Kind regards,

Frits